# Which form of past tense should be used when the gender of the speaker is unknown?

Tags: словоупотребление, род

For instance, you heard a quote from a poem or a proverb, but you don't know who exactly said it.

Do you use

Кто сказал "я к розам хочу, в тот единственный сад / Где лучшая в мире стоит из оград"?

or

Кто сказалa "я к розам хочу, в тот единственный сад / Где лучшая в мире стоит из оград"?

Comment: You should use masculine gender.

Comment: BTW, the answer is Анна Ахматова

Answer (score 14):

It does not matter whether the gender of person is known or unknown. *Кто сказала* (f.) or *кто сказало* (n.) or *кто сказали* (pl.) here would be just ungrammatical. Question word (interrogative pronoun) *кто* as a subject requires masculine singular predicate:

> Кто родил и жалеет что не сделал аборт? [[1](http://forum.forumok.ru/lofiversion/index.php?t50003.html)]
>
> Кто из женщин не сталкивался с проблемой — вещей полно, а надеть нечего? [[2](http://ratsg.ru/538-kto-iz-zhenschin-ne-stalkivalsya-s-problemoj---polno-.html)]

But when subject is complex, i. e. includes something besides *кто*, gender and number of predicate follows those of subject:

> Кто была та девушка? (fem. *была* due to *та девушка*)
> Кто они будут по национальности? (pl. *будут* due to *они*)

That’s true even if gender / number could not be identified by subject:

> Кто это была?

*это* may stand for male as well as for female, but one implies here there was a woman, so *была*.

Of course, you can hear something like:

> — Кто это был?
> — Ира, моя подруга.

but that signify that who asked the question, did not know the actual gender.

Compare it with cases when English *who* requires singular predicate regardless of most probable actual number (e. g. *Who is online?*, *Who’s coming tonight?*) – it seems to be basically the same.

Answer (score 4):

**Кто** (also кто-то, кто-нибудь, некто, никто etc.) governs **masculine singular**, while **что** (also что-то, что-нибудь, нечто, ничто etc.) governs **neuter singular**.

This holds even if you know that the answer is in a different gender, i.e. asking two girls "Кто из вас разлил молоко?" or in a sentence "Что-то звенело за дверью - то ли дверной звонок, то ли телефон."

Answer (score 0):

In the interrogative sentences like yours use the masculine form of the verb.
Кто приходил?
Кто следующий?
Кто говорит?